# C# WPF App Uninstall - Own Uninstall executable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have *C# WPF Application* with own Installer and registration to `Registry` under Uninstall path. 
App is successfully registered in Control Panel, but I want to have own Uninstaller for this app, that can call my own server and register uninstall and then remove all files and `Registry` data (This part of Uninstaller I have) when user Uninstall it with Add/Remove Programs...

I tried to add to `Registry` Uninstall path but seems that is not working.

Comment: Are you using visual studio setup project for creating installer?

Comment: Nope, I created my own installer which unpack and register app in registry. I need this approach.